# Extract type in DataExtract

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to know where custom extract type are located in the marketing cloud org[image: Sample Extracttype]

Comment: @josula Is your question "to which location do Custom Extracts output their data"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't view/change them like would File Locations. They're typically enabled by SFMC support but can also be created with Services Engagement with SFMC.